# Wordpress new post count in category widget

Tags: wordpress, categories

Wordpress.

I want to my category widget to be displayed like this in wordpress.
How can i do it and can someone help me out a bit?

*My category name (1337)* **(NEW TODAY +75)**

*1337 is total post count. The +75 is posts posted last 12hours.*

**Manuall tags:** *Wordpress New Today Posts Count*

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This better suited to SE for WP

Comment: Nothing man nothing exists. I tryed google stuff get_category get_ and so on there is nothing to be found. Its new thingy even wordpress staff deleted my psot on their forum cause its seems like its a new thing never done.

Comment: cwallenpoole, no dont do that, this is last place where i can get help. I think more people will be interessted in this later on. There is 0 on the internet about this.
My question is easy i even made so simple title explaining what problem i have.

Comment: Your question current'y doesn't meet SO guidelines. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Comment: Ok, i cant code from scratch. I have only googled alot of stuff. Get wp date post, get categry stuff and so on. Simple google stuff. But there is nothing about this. I think its a new idea and i really cant code from scratch. But little information and links and so on helps me out on a way. I really learned alot of stuff by just watching and reading code and playing with it.

Comment: Found this good information *The code for the categories widget is in wp-includes/default_widgets.php. Just copy the WP_Widget_Categories class, rename it and add your extra arguments to the wp_list_categories call.

Alternatively you can modify the arguments for the wp_list_categories call in the widget using the  widget_categories_args filter, although that will apply to all instances of the widget.*

Added some stuff and made thread cleaner.